# Make this regex code apply to words with an apostrophe

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I use this code to select 2 words around either side of a word.

```
((\w+\W+){0,2}WORDHERE(\W+\w+){0,2})
```

But it treats apostrophe-separated words as "two words".

For example, with the input text:

you're not WORDHERE is the best

the worst WORDHERE surely didn't win

The result is:

you'***re not WORDHERE is the*** best

***the worst WORDHERE surely didn***'t win

How can I make this code understand that words with an apostrophe should be treated as a single word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the pattern that you use `[^\s\r\n]+` matches any char except a whitespace or newline an could possibly also match `''''`

If you want to match apostrophe-separated words where the apostrophe is not at the start or at the end, you might use:

```
(?:\w+(?:'\w+)? ){0,2}WORDHERE(?: \w+(?:'\w+)?){0,2}
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\w+(?:'\w+)?`  Match 1+ word chars, optionally match a `'` and 1+ word chars followed by a space
- `){0,2}` Close group and repeat 0-2 times
- `WORDHERE` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\w+(?:'\w+)?` Same as the previous pattern, only the space is now at the beginning
- `){0,2}` Close group and repeat 0-2 times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C6yFXR/1)

Comment: The problem with this example is that it captures infinite words surrounding the original word. In the Regex demo, if you add words to either side, it continues to capture them. I'm looking for a way to set the amount of words on either side.

Comment: @Joe In that case you can use a quantifier `(?:\w+(?:'\w+)? ){0,2}WORDHERE(?: \w+(?:'\w+)?){0,2}` https://regex101.com/r/C6yFXR/1

Comment: That's brilliant man thanks so much for your time on this! This code seems to work better than the one I posted below, because it understands to not select, for example, HTML code. I tested and "don't stop > WORDHERE now here" doesn't select the beginning (which is GOOD). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Seems I managed to fix this by using another regex code found on SO:

```
(?:[^\s\r\n]+[\s\r\n]+[^\s\r\n]*){0,2}WORDHERE(?:[^\s\r\n]*[\s\r\n]+[^\s\r\n]+){0,2}
```